# Regular Expression conditionals, e.g. "and" / "or"

Tags: regex

Is there a way using regular expressions to find

```
grep 'a &| b &| c' #pseudo code
```

If 'a' is found also check for 'b' and if 'a' is not found also check for 'b'? etc...

Comment: This is not at all clear.  Please edit your question to include examples of strings that would match and not match.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html

Comment: will you always search for 'b'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just nest the needed values in parenthesis for and support.  Yes there is or `|`  support.

```
(ab)|(a(c|b))
```

I would have left it in a comment but don't have enough rep.

Comment: That actually does the trick. It's a lot simpler than my answer to get **and** support.

Comment: Not really as elegant as I wanted but works.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
(a)?(b)?(c)?
```

Comment: I get the sense that he wants to match *at least one of* a, b, or c, this expression will also match the empty string.